# Watir: how to clone a table cell object?

Tags: ruby, watir

I'd like to make a deep copy of a `Watir::TableCell` object.

When I called `Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(cell))`, there is an error `TypeError: singleton can't be dumped`.

I used new function `Watir::TableCell.new( cell, {:index => 0}, nil )`, but there is an error `NoMethodError: unknown property or method: 'getElementsByTagName'` when I called method `link.exists?`. It looks like the object got partial copy only.

Is there anyone having an idea to solve the problem?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to clone the TableCell?

Comment: Saved it for comparison. If the cell is in the current page, the object is fine to use a normal copy, such as c=cell. However, if the page is refreshed, c loses some info. I guess it is because the object copy function doesn't do a deep copy. I tried both dup and clone functions. They don't work in the way I expect.

Comment: Usually, you are better off saving the specific values of the cell that you are interested in, rather than the cell object itself.

Comment: It will lose lots of possibilities to expand the function capabilities.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Give us more context. Creating a deep copy of an object is probably not the easiest way to solve the problem. The last time I have used deep copy was in 2006: http://zeljkofilipin.com/ruby-deep-copy-object/

Comment: I am doing a report validation, and there are some pages for each report. The way I am using is making a copy for all pages, then validate the data later. Because there are some rich content in the report, such as icon, link, etc, it would be better to keep all the cell information, and can validate later.